# Computing posterior distribution of bayesian lasso

Tags: bayesian, self-study

I have a model:

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mu\mathbf{1}_n + \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \sim N(\mathbf{0},\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_n)$.

I have a joint prior:
$$
\pi(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2, \mu) = \pi(\mu) \pi(\sigma^2) \prod\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{\sigma^2}}e^{-\lambda|\beta_j|/\sqrt{\sigma^2}}
$$

where $\pi(\mu) \propto 1$.

I want to compute joint posterior $\pi(\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2, \mu |\mathbf{y})$ and then marginalize out $\mu$.

MY SOLUTION:

According to me, likelihood function is:
$$f(\mathbf{y} |\boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2, \mu) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\parallel \mathbf{y}- \mu \mathbf{1}_n -\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\parallel_2^2 \right)$$

Using the Bayes theorem, I got the conclusion that joint log-posterior is proportional to:
$$
\underbrace{\ln[\pi(\mu)]}_{\to \text{const.}} + \ln[\pi(\sigma^2)]-\frac{p+n}{2}\ln(\sigma^2) - \lambda \parallel \beta \parallel_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\parallel \mathbf{y}- \mu\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} \parallel_2^2
$$

HOWEVER, in paper about Bayessian Lasso (2008) written by Park and Casella they got:
$$
\ln[\pi(\sigma^2)]-\frac{p+n-1}{2}\ln(\sigma^2) - \lambda \parallel \beta \parallel_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\parallel \mathbf{\tilde{y}}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} \parallel_2^2
$$

where $\mathbf{\tilde{y}} = \mathbf{y} - \bar{y}\mathbf{1}_n$

Can someone tell me, what is the next step which will lead to a nice marginalization of $\mu$ and getting their result?

Comment: Typically, $X$ will have a constant term in it, and you might not want to shrink the coefficient of that towards 0... think about what that would imply for your prior.

Comment: OK, then lets say that $\mathbf{y}$ is demeaned by overall mean $\bar{y}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ does not include constant term.

Comment: If you do that, then your posterior is conditional upon $\mu = \bar{y}$, not what you want.  You want to integrate out $\mu$ instead.  Note that in the original paper it starts out with $\mu$ (separated from $X$), but on p. 683, column 2, they refer to "Marginalizing over $\mu$..." and the $n-1$ appears shortly thereafter.  For an analogous take on it, in classical statistics, how many degrees of freedom do you have left after you've subtracted off the sample mean?  (Think of t tests.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited the question according to them. I hope that it makes a better sense now.

Comment: Excellent!  Now, when you're coming up with the joint log-posterior, it has $\mu$ in it, but Park and Casella's version doesn't, because it's the log of the marginal posterior (with $\mu$ integrated out.)  So you'll have to integrate $\mu$ out of your expression for $f(y|\beta, \sigma^2, \mu)$, then take the log to get the "log marginal posterior".  You may (or may not) know how to do this; more hints are forthcoming if you don't.

Comment: I know how to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$. I suppose that the trick will be very similar. Make a multivariate problem somehow. Use polar coordinates and get the integral which can be computed more easily. However, I have never done it with $L_2$ norm in exponential function.

Comment: Try rewriting $\parallel y-\mu-X\beta\parallel_2$ as $\parallel y - \bar{y} - X\beta + (\bar{y}-\mu)\parallel_2$ and observing that the term in parentheses is a constant, so can be moved outside the $\parallel\dots\parallel_2$ into its own $\parallel\dots\parallel_2$ that is additive with $\parallel y - \bar{y} - X\beta\parallel_2$.  Now you've isolated $\mu$ in an expression which, if you write it out correctly, should look an awful lot like a univariate Normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2/n$.  Integrating out $\mu$ at that point can be done by eye, so to speak.

Comment: OK, I am sorry. I am totally stupid and I do not see it. $\parallel \cdots \parallel_2^2$ is a sum of squares. How can it be additive? If you explain me this, then I agree with you and the rest of the integration is easy. Thank you for your patience in advance.

Comment: No, no, it's the result of my trying to stuff everything into a comment with a limited number of characters.  $\sum(y_i-\mu-x_i\beta)^2 = \sum((y_i-\bar{y}-x_i\beta)+(\bar{y}-\mu))^2 = \sum(y_i-\bar{y}-x_i\beta)^2 + \sum(\bar{y}-\mu)^2$ and the latter sum = $n(\bar{y}-\mu)^2$.  The second equality holds because with centered $X$, $\sum(y_i-\bar{y}-x_i\beta) = 0$, so, expanding the square on the l.h.s. of the second "=", the cross-product term equals 0 and disappears, giving the r.h.s.  Hope this helps; if not, I'll probably try to put it all in an answer (which you should do once you get it!)

Comment: It helped a lot! Thank you very much! I will try to write the answer within a few days.

Answer (score 4):

So, we have:

1) Joint prior:
$$ \pi(\mu, \sigma^2, \boldsymbol{\beta}) = \pi(\sigma^2)\pi(\mu)\prod\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{\sigma^2}}e^{-\lambda|\beta_j|/\sqrt{\sigma^2}},$$

where $\pi(\mu)\propto 1$.

2) Likelihood function:
$$ f(\mathbf{y}|\mu, \sigma^2, \boldsymbol{\beta}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\| \mathbf{y}- \mu\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2 \right)$$

Using Bayes theorem we get that posterior distribution is proportional to:
$$
\pi(\sigma^2, \boldsymbol{\beta} | \mathbf{\tilde{y}}) \propto \pi(\sigma^2) \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\| \mathbf{y}- \mu\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2 \right) \prod\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{\sigma^2}}e^{-\lambda|\beta_j|/\sqrt{\sigma^2}}
$$

Now we want to integrate out $\mu$. For that we need to solve:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\| \mathbf{y}- \mu\mathbf{1}_n - \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2 \right) d\mu =\\ =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\bar{y} -\mu + y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)^2 \right) d\mu = \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \left[n\left(\bar{y} -\mu \right)^2 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)^2 + \right. \right. \\ \left. \left. +2\left(\bar{y} -\mu \right)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right) \right]\right) d\mu
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{X}_i$ is the $i$-th row of matrix $\mathbf{X}$.

There is a forgotten assumption in the setup that elements of $\mathbf{X}$ are centered. Thanks to this assumption, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right) = 0$. Because:

\begin{gather*}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i - n\bar{y} -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^p (x_{ij}^* - \bar{x}_{\cdot j})\beta_j = \\
= n\bar{y} - n\bar{y} -\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^p (x_{ij}^* - \bar{x}_{\cdot j})\beta_j
\end{gather*}

For each $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, p\}$ holds:
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_{ij}^* - \bar{x}_{\cdot j})\beta_{j} = n\bar{x}_{\cdot j}\beta_{j}-n\bar{x}_{\cdot j}\beta_{j} = 0
$$

Now back to our integral. Now we can say that it is equal to:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)^2\right) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} \left(\bar{y} -\mu \right)^2 \right) d\mu
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

From normal distribution, we know that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left( -\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} \left(\bar{y} -\mu \right)^2 \right) d\mu = 1 \ \ \ \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{n}{2\sigma^2} \left(\bar{y} -\mu \right)^2 \right) d\mu = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

The final result of posterior distribution after integrating out $\mu$ is:
$$
\pi(\sigma^2, \boldsymbol{\beta} | \mathbf{\tilde{y}}) \propto \pi(\sigma^2) \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \bar{y} - \mathbf{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)^2\right) \frac{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{n}} \prod\limits_{j=1}^{p}\frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{\sigma^2}}e^{-\lambda|\beta_j|/\sqrt{\sigma^2}}
$$

By taking log and leaving all terms without $\sigma$ we get the result.